# progressbar: GIF animation in IE slower than in FF/Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, animated-gif

I have an animated gif.

It's a progress bar and the animation is a light which is moving from left to right and then back from right to left in a loop.

The progessbar has a `width` of 250px.

Every e.g. 100ms I'm adding 1px to the width of the progessbar. So after a short time it has grown to the full size.

Then it is shown for a specific time in full size.

I've made the animation in `photoshop` and it has `58 frames` that are displayed with `0.05 seconds delay`, that the animation is smoothly.

But the animation is not smoothly (it's too slow) in `internet explorer`. In `Firefox` and `Chrome` it's working well.

What is the best do to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that IE slows down GIF animations to 0.1 when faster than 0.1. See this [bug description](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125137#c0).

For detailed explanations see also [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26994/why-is-this-gifs-animation-speed-different-in-firefox-vs-ie).

According to this [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/06/08/animated-gifs-slow-down-to-under-20-frames-per-second.aspx), **IE 10** will support up to 0.02 frame rates:

> IE10 Consumer Preview increases the supported frame-rate;
>   frames may be shown with a delay as little as 20ms. If the server
>   specifies a lower delay, the animation is delayed to 100ms for legacy
>   compatibility.